# PHP regex - Divide plain text by string object

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a file.txt with this content:

```
{"name":"merli"}{"name":"berta"}{"name":"ivan"}
{"name":"joan"}
{"name":"mireia"}{"name":"pol"}
{"name":"gerard"}
```

I am using this code, but i don't know how to separate by "}{" without losing the brackets

```
$exploded = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n|}{/', 'file.txt');
```

The result i am getting is like:

```
Array (
    0: {"name":"merli"
    1: "name":"berta"
    2: "name":"ivan"}
    3: {"name":"joan"}
    4: {"name":"mireia"
    5: "name":"pol"}
    6: {"name":"gerard"}
)
```

And I need this:

```
Array (
    0: {"name":"merli"}
    1: {"name":"berta"}
    2: {"name":"ivan"}
    3: {"name":"joan"}
    4: {"name":"mireia"}
    5: {"name":"pol"}
    6: {"name":"gerard"}
)
```

Comment: Looks like invalid json.

Comment: You'd be better off manually editing it once, and fixing the code that graced you with this format in the first place. Else: [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I edited the publication because it was not completely correct. The file is the output of an automatic proccess, and the file has lot of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop over the string characters and don't involve with `\r` and `\n` characters at all. Find `{`, find `}` and have all characters in between them in `$temp` as shown below.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '{"name":"merli"}{"name":"berta"}{"name":"ivan"}
{"name":"joan"}
{"name":"mireia"}{"name":"pol"}
{"name":"gerard"}';

$result = [];
$len = strlen($str);

for($i = 0;$i < $len;++$i){
    while($i < $len && $str[$i] != '{') $i++;
    $temp = '';
    while($i < $len && $str[$i] != '}') $temp .= $str[$i++];
    $temp .= '}';
    $result[] = $temp;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/1OFen

Answer (score 1):

I suppose

```
$exploded = str_replace('}{', "}\n{", $file_contents);
```

is enough.

And as file contents look like **invalid json** it will be better to fix it.

Comment: The OP says using a regex.

Comment: @user2342558  Many people aren't aware of the inefficiencies of using regex, and just assume that it is the best way to solve the problem.  However, for simple cases like this, is usually is not.

Comment: correct, but I didn't suppose that the OP was asking for a different approach than the one he asked for

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$fileContents = '
{"name":"merli"}{"name":"berta"}{"name":"ivan"}
{"name":"joan"}
{"name":"mireia"}{"name":"pol"}
{"name":"gerard"}
';

// $matches is the array containing each matche found
preg_match_all('/{[^{]+}+?/', $fileContents, $matches);

// to rearrange $matches as plaintext
echo $result = join("\n", $matches[0]);
```

output:

```
{"name":"merli"}
{"name":"berta"}
{"name":"ivan"}
{"name":"joan"}
{"name":"mireia"}
{"name":"pol"}
{"name":"gerard"}
```

You can try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6223aa262158dde7087c0b36f75c5259c1c1082).

This will catch also text like `{"name":"..."} {"name":"..."}` and `{"name":"..."}everyOtherUnexpectedChar{"name":"..."}`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because you remove delimiter when you split. Either you have to create more complicated preg_split, or you have to combine replace and split. Try this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n/', '', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/}{/', '},{', $content);
$exploded = preg_split('/,/', $content);
```